# Flex Datagrid insert row below current row

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, insert, row

my application needs to allow users to insert rows below the current datagrid row. My solution is to to add a row to the dataproviders collection. This works, but the row does not appear beneath the current row the user clicked on.

The Datagrid has a default sort order (date ASC), which re-orders the data...so this seems to affect the position of the row in the grid.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible answers:
1. define your own sort function that sorts according to item order in dataprovider (i.e. it does nothing), and assign it to the sortFunction property
2. simply comment out the sorting of the data inside the component.